# Laravel + sail + dusk => Error: Could not start a new session [...] Chrome failed to start

Tags: selenium, laravel-dusk, laravel-sail

I just can't get Laravel dusk running. I've searched the internet and tried almost everything. I hope anyone knows the trick.

To rule out any self introduced problems I stated with a brand new Laravel project: `curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash`. I'm using a Macbook Air (M1 chip) and therefore I have to change the `docker-compose.yml` and add `platform=linux/amd64` to the containers. Thereafter ran `./vendor/bin/sail build` and started up the containers. Next installed Dusk: `./vendor/bin/sail composer require --dev laravel/dusk` and ran the install command (`./vendor/bin/sail artisan dusk:install`) as by the documentation.

At this point no additional modifications in any file have been made. Laravel Dusk ships with the default browser test. (tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php) When I run the command `./vendor/bin/sail dusk` the following error will show:

```
1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'
System info: host: '64671e354051', ip: '192.168.32.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.76-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.13'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'
System info: host: '64671e354051', ip: '192.168.32.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.76-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.13'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

/var/www/html/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:125
/var/www/html/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:372
/var/www/html/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:131
/var/www/html/tests/DuskTestCase.php:46
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:219
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:243
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:220
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:98
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:66
/var/www/html/tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php:21
```

### What I tried

- The files in `./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/` have the right permissions.
- `./vendor/bin/sail artisan dusk:chrome-driver --all` => `ChromeDriver binary successfully installed for version 100.0.4896.60.` . But the same dusk error will show.
- Tried to run the ChromeDriver directly: `./vendor/bin/sail bash` => `./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux`. This results in an error:

```
./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I Found an other StackOverflow post to fix this issue by installing the following packages via the sail root-shell: `apt update; apt install libnss3-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libxss-dev;`. Now the chromedriver-linux is starting without errors. Dusk still fails with the same error.

Has anyone a clue?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when running `sail artisan dusk`.

When started using `sail dusk` instead everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

After a long, tiring road of trying to get Sail/Docker working, have got to the point where Xdebug/VSCode and Unit Tests are working...

Next in line was '**dusk**'

```
$ sail dusk
```

**ERROR  Command "dusk" is not defined.**

All of the settings are as in:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#laravel-dusk

I really want to get everything working in Sail, before I commit to learning Laravel. Not much on Google for this issue.